# Pass URL on button click ionic

Tags: javascript, json, angular, ionic-framework

I am creating an ionic app which read data from json url. There are two pages.

I want to pass the url on button click from 1st page to 2nd page so that in 2nd page the url is read and data is displayed.

1st Page: Home
2nd Page: Home-details.

My home.html looks like below:

```
<button ion-button color="primary" round full style="height: 50px;" (click)="start($event, item)" [disabled]="startbuttonDisabled">
START!
</button>
```

My home.ts looks like below:

```
start(event: any,item: any) {
this.navCtrl.push(homedetailspage, {
item:item
});
}
```

My home-details.ts looks like below:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, protected httpClient: HttpClient, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {

this.value = navParams.get('item');
console.log(this.value);

this.httpClient.get(this.value)
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.jsonitems = res;
        },
      error=>{
        console.log(error);
      } );
}
```

I want to pass the JSON url `"assets/data/data.json"` in the variable "item" to the 2nd page home-details.ts

Please suggest me where i am doing the mistake.

Comment: Does it work if you remove `this.value = navParams.get('item');` from the constructor and put it in the `ionViewWillEnter` hook for example?

Comment: It worked but i had to move the complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following changes were made and the issue is resolved.

In home.ts, below is the updated code:

```
start(event: any,item: any) {
this.navCtrl.push(homedetailspage, {
item:'assets/data/data.json'
});
}
```

In home-details.ts, below is the updated code(removed from constructor):

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.value = this.navParams.get('item');
    console.log("url", this.value);
   
    this.httpClient.get(this.value)
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.fullbodyitems = res;
        },
      error=>{
        console.log(error);
      } );
  }
```